# Bootbox alert not on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bootbox

I'm calling bootbox confirm function, but it isn't on focus. All my page get this gray effect, including the bootbox window. What am I doing wrong?

[image: bootbox problem]

Here's how I am calling bootbox confirm function:

```
$(".js-delete").on("click", function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var button = $(this);

            bootbox.confirm("Você tem certeza que deseja deletar esse registro de cliente?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "@Url.Action("Delete","Customers")",
                        ajaxasync: true,
                        data: { id: button.attr("customer-id") },
                        success: tr.remove()
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try opening browser dev tools console, are there any styling/JS errors found? Also check out classes applied to modal (I suspected `.modal-backdrop` or `.modal-bootstrap` styling messing up there).

Comment: Those buttons don't look like the default styles for Bootstrap 3 or Bootstrap 4 - are you using a theme of some sort? Bootbox itself doesn't have it's own CSS, so this seems like a conflict in the version of Bootstrap used and/or an incorrect override from the theme being used.